# Why can I see a smb share through the Terminal but not on Finder?

Tags: macos, samba, finder

Why can I see a samba share through the Terminal but not on Finder?
Below the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is the format of the drive you are attempting to access via SMB/Finder?
If the disc is formatted as a NTFS file system then you will need a interpreter for MacOS to access the NTFS volume.